# First use of an acronym with \acp with acro package shows strange result

Tags: acronyms, acro

I have problems with the \acp from the acro package.

Here an minimal example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{MP}{
        short = {MP},
        long = {Member of Parliament},
        long-plural-form = {Members of Parliament}
}
\begin{document}
\acp{MP}
\end{document}
```

It shows `$\Delta$ (MPs)` (latex notation) as result instead of `Members of Parliament (MPs)`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug and is resolved with an update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by an update to recent acro version (2.2b).